# Regular expressions with back references

Tags: regex, grep, backreference

So I have this really long file in which there are lines that are built like this:

```
`somecode [ somecode > somecode ] somecode > somecode > somecode`
```

I have to search for a string of atleast 9 + or - characters between the brackets and the same thing that was matched between those brackets have to be found between the two '>' next to the brackets...
So far I came up with this;

```
`cat file | egrep -n '*\[.*([-+]{9,}).*\].*(>).*\1.*(>).*' > out.txt`
```

Comment: The code I use to grep doesn't work... Terminal keeps working on the job, but doesn't give any output

Comment: @Pieterjan what kind of output do you want

Comment: Maybe, it's working really hard on your regexp, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html for a possible explanation.

Comment: Could be, the file I need to search is over a 100 000 lines long... @Fake I want to have the full lines of where the regex are matched. Its just a string of 9 +'s between brackets, the same one has to be found between the >'s and the line has to be printed where it was found...

Comment: Applying regex with backreferences on 100,000 lines is not a good idea - I would expect out of memory error, server halt or very long run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess from your regex,this is what you wanted to do

```
\[.*?([+-]{9,}).*?\].*?>.*?\1.*?>
```

if you want to get the full line use this

```
^.*?\[.*?([+-]{9,}).*?\].*?>.*?\1.*?>.*?$
```